# Post List of Data to API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am currently working on an API and I want to post a list of data to the API.
this is an e-commerce example, so I would need to pass the multiple items in the cart as per the line no, line no will auto-increment. and order should be posted with the same order ID but with a different order number.

This is what the Json looks like -

```
    {
    "VarFID": 1,
    "VarCID": 1,
    "VarAreaCode": 1,
    "VarAge": 250,
    "VarB": 20,
    "VarF": 1,
    "VarC": 256,
    "VarF": 1,
    "OrderLines": [
        {
            "OrderID": "SQ/19/10",
            "Line No_": 1,
            "Date": "2019-04-02 00:00:00",
            "Time": "2019-04-02 11:38:48",
            "No_": "FAG-033",
            "Name": "LC GOLD",
            "Quantity":000,
            "Unit Price": 10000,
            "Amount": 10000,
            "Status": "Under Processing",
            "Remarks": "VIKRAM",
            "VariantCode":3
        },
        {
            "OrderID": "SQ/19/10",
            "Line No_": 2,
            "Date": "2019-04-02 00:00:00",
            "Time": "2019-04-02 11:38:48",
            "No_": "F061",
            "Name": "LC S - I",
            "Quantity": 00,
            "Unit Price": 100,
            "Amount": 300,
            "Status": "Under Processing",
            "Remarks": "VIKRAM ",
            "VariantCode":2
        }

    ]
}
```

This is the code I am using to generate the array, the data is going through, but it is only posting one item/line and not both of them.

```
      void sendData2() async {
    mainModel = MainModel(
        VarFID: "1",
        VarCID: "1",
        VarAreaCode: "1",
        VarAge: "1",
        VarB: "1",
        VarF: "1",
        VarC: "1",
        VarF: "1",
        OrderLines: listOrderLines.OrderLines);
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('softwareonus.com:8082', '/admindealerlist/'),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: json.encode(mainModel.toJson()),
    );

    print(" Send Data 2 Response  : ${response.body}");
    print(" Send Data 2 Response  : ${response.statusCode}");
  }
```

I have created model classes using JsonSerialazble

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `body: json.encode(mainModel.toJson()),` which is pointless since your function `.toJson()` in your model already does the `json.encode(..)` for you. You should just `.post` your `mainModel.toJson()` to your API.

Comment: Are you saying i should use this?Could you clarify the same a bit? are you saying i should use this ? ' var response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('softwareonus.com:8082', '/admindealerlist/'),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: mainModel.toJson(),
    );'

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data, you have shared. Create 2 Model Classes-

1. Object Model Class of each object you have
2. Super Model class (use Object Model Class here like the code)

code Snippet:

1. ObjectModel-:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'ObjectModel.g.dart'; // you have to use naming convention of like this (yourfilename.g.dart)

@JsonSerializable()
class ObjectModel 
  {
        String orderId;
        String lineNo;
        //All other variable define here

        // Initilize all in the constructor
        ObjectModel({this.orderId,this.lineNo,[.... your othersVariable...]});
        @override
  factory ObjectModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ObjectModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ObjectModelToJson(this);
    
}
```

2. SuperModel:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'SuperModel.g.dart'; ///you have to use naming convention of like this (yourfilename.g.dart)

@JsonSerializable()
class SuperModel {
  String varFid;
  String varCID;
  // alll othervarialble...
  List<ObjectModel> orderLines;

  //initilize all in constructor
  SuperModel({ this.varFid,this.varCID ,[.....otherVariable],this.orderLines });
  factory SuperModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SuperModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SuperModelToJson(this);
}
```

Note: To create Model Classes I am using this two packages and I have put that in dev_dependency:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  json_serializable: ^3.3.0
```

Now you have to run the below command to generate the g.dart file

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Now finally you can do HTTP Post request and model class like this-

```
 void send() async {
\\SuperModel supermodel = SuperModel ([initialize data to this model class])

    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.https('softwareonus.com:8082', '/admindealerlist/'),
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode(supermodel .toJson()));
    print(response.body);
    
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can watch my Model Class series on Youtube Here is the link: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtIU0BH0pkKpXE-1vC7NswofFPby1OYh-

Thanks :)

Update:

Suppose there is a button in your app, when you click on the button then you add the data on the list

```
class _ListDataState extends State<ListData> {
  SuperModel superModel = SuperModel ();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // your UI code
  }

 
 void add() {
    setState(() {
      superModel.orderLines.add(ObjectModel(Your all variable initialize here);
    });
   
  }
```

Call this add method whenever you wanted to add new order in your list. After adding all data send it using send method

```
 void send() async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.https('softwareonus.com:8082', '/admindealerlist/'),
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode(supermodel .toJson()));
    print(response.body);

  }
```

Comment: Thank you much for answering my question here, i have been able to send data to the api using this method, challenge i am facing is, how can i send the data in one go if there are multiple lines in the orderlines?

Comment: What should my add function look like here?

Comment: see you need to create a list of object model where you need to assign the data of object then at the last use supermodel ,

Comment: my addd function is only adding the last item to the list of order lines and not all the items.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace  with your object class, which must have the toJson() method that returns the Map.
2. import 'dart:convert' on to your API function class
3. And don't forget to add,
    `headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': application/json'},`

   ```
    Future<bool> addToSaleDetail(List<YourCustomObject> _listOfObject) async {

        String unparsedUrl = "$baseUrl/AddMobileListSaleBrief";
        var url = Uri.parse(unparsedUrl);

        List jsonList = [];
        _listOfObject.map((item) => jsonList.add(item.toJson())).toList();

        final response = await http.post(
          url,
          body: json.encode({"finalResponse": jsonList}["finalResponse"]),
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `mainModel` to `Map<String, dynamic>` then encode your `Map<String, dynamic>` to json and send it to body. Add this `'Content-type': 'application/json'` to your headers to make your request sent as json. For Example :

```
    List<Map<String, String>> listItem = <Map<String, String>>[];
    for (var element in myList) {
      Map<String, String> val = {
        'product': element.product.id_product.toString(),
        'quantity': element.quantity.toString(),
        'total': element.total.toString(),
      };
      listItem.add(val);
    }
    Map data = {
      'pay': pay,
      'customer': id_customer.toString(),
      'items': listItem, // this is a List
    };
    final http.Response response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(...), // your url
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json' // don't forget this one
      },
      body: jsonEncode(data), // encode my Map to json
    );
```

That's it! (by the way this is example of my code)